# Missing Google Markers In IE8

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please with a error that I can't explain.

I was using [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/mylocations.html) page yesterday and the markers were plotted on the map correctly. However, I've gone back in today and the markers have disapeared. I've also tried other files and I've got the same issue.

I know that the co-ordinates are being plotted on the map, because if I select the location in the left hand sidebar, the 'detail map' renders as it should, I've also checked the page with Firefox and the markers are shown.

I've reinstalled Interent Explorer and I've still got this problem. Could someone perhaps tell me please has anyone else come across this or a similar problem, and could someone perhaps please provide some guidnace on what I've done wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your placeholder icon;

```
icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
```

is a 404 so not displayed.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying to my post. Forgive for asking a really stupid question. Have I got it right then that my file is correct but the filepath for the icon no longer exists? Kind regards

Comment: Yes, your source code sets some icons in `var customIcons = { ` that do not exist (paste their urls into a browser) for example the green pin is http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png but that's not a valid image (anymore). Google for "mm_20_green.png"   copy & host it locally. (The F12 tools in your browser will show errors like this)